# how to remove partial duplicates in a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a list of lists where it looks like

```
[[1,'a',2],[1,'b',2],[1,'a',3]]
```

I want to remove the item from the list if the second element in the list of lists are the same (e.g. they are both `a`)

I want to create output that looks like:

```
[[1,'a',2],[1,'b',2]]
```

where it grabs the first one in the list of the duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's a variant of [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order).

You can use a marker set to track the already appended sublists since strings are immutable so hashable & storable in a `set`:

```
lst = [[1,'a',2],[1,'b',2],[1,'a',3]]

marker_set = set()

result = []

for sublist in lst:
    second_elt = sublist[1]
    if second_elt not in marker_set:
        result.append(sublist)
        marker_set.add(second_elt)

print(result)
```

prints:

```
[[1, 'a', 2], [1, 'b', 2]]
```

(using a marker *set* and not a *list* allows an average `O(1)` lookup instead of `O(N)`)

Comment: what are the benefits of using `set` here over a plain list

Comment: Of course, I figured that, I should have known it was speed related didn't know if there were any other reasons, great work!

Comment: thanks. Actually this question is borderline duplicate, but I figured that closing it as a duplicate wouldn't be enough for OP & others to solve that particular one.

Comment: if you have an exact duplicate you can share the link

Comment: actually this is a slight off variant of results I found, if I come across one , will link

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary where the second element is the key, on the reverse of the list, to drop duplicates:

```
dct = {j: (i, k) for i, j, k in reversed(L)}
```

```
{'a': (1, 2), 'b': (1, 2)}
```

---

Getting the result back as a list:

```
[[i, j, k] for j, (i, k) in dct.items()]
```

```
[[1, 'a', 2], [1, 'b', 2]]
```

While this solution *will* always keep the first occurence of a duplicate, the relative order of elements is not guaranteed in the final result.

Comment: Honest question, is slicing that way better than `reversed`?

Comment: Not really, but it means my one liners can be shorter :P

Comment: you can use `reversed` in your one-liner. It's better because it doesn't create a new list.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre but that's 4 more characters, so clearly much more inefficient ;)

Comment: Worth noting that this approach will work as expected only in Python 3.7 and above. Otherwise, `dct` may be in any arbitrary order.

Comment: @DeepSpace I note in the answer the relative order may be changed.  However, the correct duplicates will always be removed, because the input is a list that is iterated over

Comment: I just noticed he says the second element, not the first two, I need to update my answer anyways

Comment: dicts are ordered by implementation in python 3.6, and it's guaranteed in python 3.7. It was a long wait :)

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [[1,'a',2],[1,'b',2],[1,'a',3]]
res = []
for i in lst:
    if not any(i[1] in j for j in res):
        res.append(i)

print(res)
# [[1, 'a', 2], [1, 'b', 2]]
```

Comment: don't sort just to use `groupby`, that's inefficient

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre should look for alternatives that dont involve rearranging original list then?

Comment: yes; `groupby` is really neat when the items to group are contiguous. Else `sort` kills the fun, introducting useless `O(N*log(N))` complexity when `O(N)` does it

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thank you , so reserve groupby for when we don't have to rearrange the list, got it

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre better?

Comment: this solution will be slower but would work on non-mutable items so yes